# Mongo query for session length

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

In Mongo I have a document with two fields, SessionId, and Ticks; SessionId being a key, and Ticks being a long int for ticks since some point in time.

What I'd like to do is group them by SessionId, and get the diff between the max Ticks, and min Ticks, for that session. In SQL it would be pretty easy:

```
SELECT sessionId, MAX(ticks) - MIN(ticks) as session_length
FROM weblog
GROUP BY sessionId
```

But in Mongo, this seems to be a fairly involved MapReduce.
How would you guys do it? MapReduce? JS for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your data model, you could use the group command:

```
db.coll.group({
    key:{session:true}, 
    initial: {max: 0, min:100}, 
    reduce: function(obj, prev){
       if(obj.ticks > prev.max){
          prev.max=obj.ticks;
       }
       if(obj.ticks <prev.min){
          prev.min=obj.min;
       }
     },
     finalize: function(out){
       out.session_length=out.max - out.min;
     }
 })
```

example input:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "session" : 1, "ticks" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "session" : 1, "ticks" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 3, "session" : 1, "ticks" : 12 }
{ "_id" : 4, "session" : 2, "ticks" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 5, "session" : 2, "ticks" : 8 }
{ "_id" : 6, "session" : 2, "ticks" : 3 }
```

example output:

```
   [
    {
        "session" : 1,
        "max" : 12,
        "min" : 4,
        "session_length" : 8
    },
    {
        "session" : 2,
        "max" : 8,
        "min" : 3,
        "session_length" : 5
    }
]
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group

Comment: In MongoDB version 2.2 (the next stable release), the new aggregation framework will make it possible to do this type of aggregation without Javascript.  Also, if you may want to store min and max values with the sessionID to maximize query performance.  Here is the link to the new aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/